# How do I enable command blocks on a Forge-based server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to enable command blocks on a server I set up. I've been trying to find a command or something to get it to work but nothing IS working. I tried gamerules but that didn't work either. Help me ;-;

Comment: I don't know much about forge but with a vanilla server this is done in the [server.properties](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server.properties) file.

Comment: Thanks IronAnvil, but I can't find it! I had seen this answer before. Do you have an idea where I could find it?

Comment: Find what?  Find the file?  It is in the same directory as the server jar file.  If you are talking about inside the file look for enable-command-block and make it equal true.

Answer (score 0):

Command blocks can be enabled by editing the [server.properties](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties) file which usually located in the root directory or the folder which the server jar file is.

It is the file which stores all the settings for a multiplayer server.

You will find the line:

```
enable-command-block=false
```

Set it to:

```
enable-command-block=true
```